# Windows 10 on HP Elitebook detects USB3 external HD on USB3 ports as USB2

Tags: windows-10, usb-3, usb-2, hp-elitebook

On a recently bought used HP Elitebook, both the USB 3.0 ports detect my USB 3.0 external Toshiba HDD as USB 2. That Toshiba HDD has an LED which glows blue when connected to a USB 3.0 port, or white when connected to a USB 2.0 port. Whenever I connect it to either of the USB 3.0 ports on my laptop, it shows a white light, which slows down the drive. How do I test to see where the problem is?

Comment: USB3 and Bluetooth - Never rely on either for anything important and your experience with IT will be far more productive! Try a different cable - preferably shorter in length. Describe or post a picture of what kind of cable you hae

Comment: Alternatively (or in addition) to @K7AAY advice, plug a known good USB 3.0 flash drive into your recently bought (but used) Elitebook, and see if it connects at SuperSpeed rate (ether by means of benchmark, or using USBTreeView). It is possible that proper xHCI drivers were not installed.

Comment: Thank you @K7AAY The usb3.0 cable to the hard drive has no issue. I have already tested in on a friends usb3.0 port computer and it shows the blue light. From what I have read, i think its my windows. I will try updating it and see what happens